# Как будет выглядеть часть кода vba на c#?

Tags: c#, vba

Подскажите как будет выглядеть эти два кусочка кода на c#?

```
tmp_String = Trim(In_String) 
tmp_Length = Len(tmp_String) 
If tmp_Length <> 8 Then
    tmp_Out = False
Else
    tmp_Out = True
End If

tmp_Out = tmp_Out And IsNumeric(tmp_String)

If (tmp_Out = True) Then
    N1 = Val(Left(tmp_String, 1))
    N2 = Val(Mid(tmp_String, 2, 1))
    N3 = Val(Mid(tmp_String, 3, 1))
    N4 = Val(Mid(tmp_String, 4, 1))
Else
End if
```

---

```
If (K8 < 10) Then
    tmp_Des = 10
    tmp_Ed = Val(Right(Trim(Str(K8)), 1))
Else
    tmp_Des = (Val(Left(Trim(Str(K8)), 1)) + 1) * 10
    tmp_Ed = Val(Right(Trim(Str(K8)), 1))
End If
```

Вызвала трудности эта строка `tmp_Out = tmp_Out And IsNumeric(tmp_String)`

Comment: Что именно вызвало трудности? описание какой VB-функции Вы не можете найти?

Comment: @Akina вот эта строка tmp_Out = tmp_Out And IsNumeric(tmp_String)

Comment: Собственно эта строка, совместно с предыдущим кодом, проверяет, что введенная строка после удаления обрамляющих пробелов оставляет строку в 8 символов, содержащую только цифры, десятичный разделитель (не более 1), возможно ведущий минус, и пробелы (например, `"-, 1 2 3"` - легитимно с точки зрения этого кода). Однако следующий код предполагает, что первые 4 символа будут цифрами, что может быть неверным (в переменные N1..N4 для таких символов будет присвоен ноль). Рекомендую переписать этот код полностью.

Answer (score 1):

Для преобразования многих стандартных типов между собой можно использовать статический класс Convert с его многочисленными методами

`Val(str)` >> `Convert.ToInt32(str)`

Аналогов Right и Left нет в стандартных средствах, поэтому придётся использовать метод извлечения подстроки.

`Right(str,len)` >> `str.Substring(str.Length -len, len)`

`Left(str,len)` >> `str.Substring(0,len)`

С обрезанием пробелов с двух сторон и взятием длины строки всё просто

`Trim(str)` >> `str.Trim()`

`Len(str)` >> `str.Length()`

С методом взятия подстроки нужно учитывать нюанс. В c# нумерация символов начинается с 0, а в VBA с 1

`Mid(str,pos,len)` >> `str.Substring(pos-1,len)`

Аналогом IsNumeric можно считать Int32.TryParse, только он мощнее -- ещё и результат возвращает во втором выходном параметре. Но раз он нам не нужен, его можно проигнорировать с помощью `_`

`IsNumeric(str)` >> `Int32.TryParse(str, out _)`

И так, вот как преобразуются, например, следующие выражения

`(Val(Left(Trim(Str(K8)), 1)) + 1) * 10` >> `(Convert.ToInt32(K8.ToString().Trim().SubString(0,1)) + 1) * 10`

`tmp_Out = tmp_Out And IsNumeric(tmp_String)` >>

`tmp_Out &= Int32.TryParse(tmp_string, out _);`

Объяснять про разницу в блоках if-else я думаю здесь не стоит. Также и переводить весь код на c# и печатать здесь полный листинг.

---

Ещё пару слов про `And`. Полным аналогом `flag1 = flag1 And flag2` будет
`flag1 = flag1 & flag2`. Его можно сократить так, как я указал выше `flag1 &= flag2`. Но правильным вариантом с учётом семантики вашего кода будет `flag1 = flag1 && flag2`. Потому что, оператор `&&` сэкономит машинное время и не станет вычислять правое выражение, если flag1 равен false. Аналогов в VBA такому удобному поведению, насколько я знаю, нет.

Comment: `IsNumeric` не заменяется `Int32.TryParse` полностью, ибо `IsNumeric`: не делает различий между целыми и нецелыми, а также не детектирует переполнение, ибо не ограничена типом; игнорирует пробелы; допускает шестнадцатиричные значения с префиксом `&H`; ну и ещё несколько тонкостей - и не все могут быть исправлены соответствующим `NumberStyles`.